# An error occured while executing doInBackground

Tags: android, ftp, android-asynctask

I want to connect with FTP and get frome there list of files. This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    task getson = new task();
    getson.execute();

}

FTPClient client;

public FTPClient connectWithFTP() throws IOException{
     client = new FTPClient();  
     try {

         client.connect("server", 21);  
         client.login("username", "password");
         System.out.println("status :: " + client.getReplyString());
         int reply = client.getReplyCode();
            if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
                throw new Exception("Connect failed: " + client.getReplyString());
            }
            try {
                client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                if (!client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE)) {
                    Log.v(getClass().toString(), "Setting binary file type failed.");
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
         checkFiles(client);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("status :: " + client.getReplyString());
    }
      return client;
}

private class task extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, FTPClient> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // Do stuff before the operation
    }


    @Override
    protected FTPClient doInBackground(Void... params) {
        FTPClient ftp = null;
        try {
            ftp = connectWithFTP();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public void disconnectWithFTP() throws IOException{
    client.logout();  
    client.disconnect();  
}

private void checkFiles(FTPClient clients){
      try {  
          FTPFile[] ftpFiles = clients.listFiles();  
          int length = ftpFiles.length;  
          for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {  
            String name = ftpFiles[i].getName();  
            Calendar date = ftpFiles[i].getTimestamp();
            Log.v("aasd", name+", "+date);

          }  
        } catch(Exception e) {  
          e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

**Logcat**

```
01-22 20:05:46.994: E/AndroidRuntime(616): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask
#1 01-22 20:05:46.994: E/AndroidRuntime(616): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground() 01-22 20:05:46.994: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
01-22 20:05:46.994:   E/AndroidRuntime(616):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)                    01-22 20:05:46.994: E/AndroidRuntime(616):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125) 
01-22 20:05:46.994: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308) 
01-22 20:05:46.994: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) 
01-22 20:05:46.994: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088) 
01-22 20:05:46.994: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581) 
01-22 20:05:46.994: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)   
01-22 20:05:46.994: E/AndroidRuntime(616): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient 
01-22 20:05:46.994: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at com.example.listfile.MainActivity.connectWithFTP(MainActivity.java:38) 
01-22 20:05:46.994: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at com.example.listfile.MainActivity$task.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:75) 
01-22 20:05:46.994: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at com.example.listfile.MainActivity$task.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1) 
01-22 20:05:46.994: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185) 
01-22 20:05:46.994: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306) 
01-22 20:05:46.994: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  ... 4 more
```

Comment: Are you using some external jars in your lib folder?

Answer (score 2):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient
at com.example.listfile.MainActivity.connectWithFTP(MainActivity.java:38)
```

The apache FTPClient library not found.

You have to add the library to your project. The important thing is to copy the library to your projects "libs" folder. Then you can reference it this way (assuming you use Eclipse):

Project --> Properties --> Java Build Path --> Libraries --> Add Jars

Don't forget to tick the library in "Order and Export" after you have added the jar.

Comment: The user seem to be implementing himself this method, so I believe it's not an external library (and that's why I asked about it)

Comment: Well, the full class name is "org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient" so I guess its external:)

Comment: i'm add jar in libraries but i can't run project.

Comment: Have you added it to the "libs" folder? Have you added it to the Build Path as I described above? Have you ticked the lib in the "Order and Export" section? Also, try to clean the project after you finished.

Comment: Oh i just copy and past your jar file into that libs folde it's work ,

Comment: how to get file list in android lisview and checkbok ?